# Pandas track consecutive near numbers via compare-cumsum-groupby pattern

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to extend my current pattern to accommodate extra conditions of +- a percentage of the last value rather than strict does it match previous value.

```
data = np.array([[2,30],[2,900],[2,30],[2,30],[2,30],[2,1560],[2,30],
[2,300],[2,30],[2,450]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['id','interval']
```

UPDATE 2 (id fix): Updated Data 2 with more data:

```
data2 = np.array([[2,30],[2,900],[2,30],[2,29],[2,31],[2,30],[2,29],[2,31],[2,1560],[2,30],[2,300],[2,30],[2,450], [3,40],[3,900],[3,40],[3,39],[3,41], [3,40],[3,39],[3,41] ,[3,1560],[3,40],[3,300],[3,40],[3,450]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2.columns = ['id','interval']

for i, g in df.groupby([(df.interval != df.interval.shift()).cumsum()]):
   if len(g.interval.tolist())>=3:
        print(g.interval.tolist())
```

**results in `[30,30,30]`**

however I really want to catch near number conditions say when a number is **+-10%** of the previous number.

**so looking at df2 I would like to pickup the series `[30,29,31]`**

```
for i, g in df2.groupby([(df2.interval != <???+- 10% magic ???>).cumsum()]):
   if len(g.interval.tolist())>=3:
        print(g.interval.tolist())
```

UPDATE:  Here is the end of line processing code where I store the gathered lists into a dictionary with the ID as the key

```
leak_intervals = {}
final_leak_intervals = {}
serials = []
for i, g in df.groupby([(df.interval != df.interval.shift()).cumsum()]):
    if len(g.interval.tolist()) >= 3:
        print(g.interval.tolist())
        serial = g.id.values[0]
        if serial not in serials:
            serials.append(serial)
        if serial not in leak_intervals:
            leak_intervals[serial] = g.interval.tolist()
        else:
            leak_intervals[serial] = leak_intervals[serial] + (g.interval.tolist())
```

Comment: perhaps [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) could help?

Comment: why would you select the first `30` then? the previous value is `900` so the difference is much more than 10%... Following your logic it should be only `[29, 31]`

Comment: @MaxU Sorry you are right in that case, I tried to just simplify the data.  What I am trying to do is keep track of series of near / like values so i can get a baseline reading of a condition in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [116]: df2.groupby(df2.interval.pct_change().abs().gt(0.1).cumsum()) \
             .filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3)
Out[116]:
    id  interval
2    2        30
3    2        29
4    2        31
5    2        30
6    2        29
7    2        31
15   3        40
16   3        39
17   2        41
18   2        40
19   2        39
20   2        41
```

Comment: Im not sure that works.  First it shouldn't pickup the 300 and preferably i would get a list of the values like i have in my original code.  However the code is interesting.  What does lt(10).diff() do ?

Comment: Almost there, see my latest edit for the extra code.  The idea is I am trying to isolate a varying condition that varies greatly between IDs and slightly for that ID.   So i track a list then average out of the list to determine my generic "value" for that particular ID in the dataset

Comment: Definitely a great head start, I will work with it and post back if i completely solve it.

Comment: @CaseyKnauss, i don't really understand the issue - could you elaborate?